# Name: 'carbs' is not defined

Tags: python

Here is my python code:

```
def output(carbs, fat, pro, fiber):
        carbs = carbs*4
        pro = pro*4
       fat = fat*9
       fiber = fiber*4
       final = carbs + fat + pro - fiber
       if(final >= 500):
            print("Food: ", "Total Calories: ", final)
        elif(final < 100):
            print("Food: Salad", "Total Calories: ", final)
        elif(final < 500 and final <= 100):
            print("Food: Hamburger", "Total Calories: ", final)
def main():

        print('''___________               .___ _________        .__               .__          __               
\_   _________   ____   __| _/ \_   ___ \_____  |  |   ____  __ __|  | _____ _/  |_ 
___________ 
 |    __)/  _ \ /  _ \ / __ |  /    \  \/\__  \ |  | _/ ___\|  |  |  | \__  \\   __/  _ \_  
__     \
 |     \(  <_> (  <_> / /_/ |  \     \____/ __ \|  |_\  \___|  |  |  |__/ __ \|  |(  <_> |  
| \/
 \___  / \____/ \____/\____ |   \______  (____  |____/\___  |____/|____(____  |__| 
 \____/|__|   
      \/                    \/          \/     \/          \/                \/    ''')

    print("ADD CARBOHYDRATES, FAT, PROTEIN, AND FIBER")

    carbs_input = int(input("Carbohydrate content: "))
    fat_input = int(input("Fat content: "))
    pro_input = int(input("Protein content: "))
    fiber_input = int(input("Fiber content: "))
    output(carbs, fat, pro, fiber)
main()
```

Python is telling me that output(carbs, fat, pro, fiber) is not defined. Namely 'carbs'. I think it has to do with the output function.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you understand from that error message? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: You should passing in your variables to output like `output(carbs_input, fat_input,` ....

Answer (score 0):

Where are you unclear?  Your call to `output` uses four variables, *none* of which is defined in that scope.  You define variables `carbs_input, fat_input, pro_input, fiber_input`, but those are the only ones.  Try using the variables you defined, instead of those "ghost" variables.

```
output(carbs_input, fat_input, pro_input, fiber_input)
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  If `main` runs, then it calls `output`.